# Unit Test Asynchronous network call using popsicle in javascript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, promise, mocha.js

I'm writing a simple javascript sdk and I am creating a wrapper around the [popsicle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/popsicle) request object and write a fetch method. It looks something like this.

```js
import request from 'popsicle';

export default function fetchPosts(postsRequest) {
    // some validations
    const url = 'api/posts';
    const postsRequestData = Object.assign({}, balboaRequest, {url});
    if (!authPreflightPromise) {
        authPreflightPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // Disable auth preflight if configured to do so.
            if (!postsRequest.enableAuthPreflight) {
                resolve();
            }

            const authPreflightUrl = 'http://somedomain.com/auth?state=hasArgs';
            const authPreflightRequestData = Object.assign({}, {method: 'POST'}, {url: authPreflightUrl});
            request(authPreflightRequestData)
                .then(() => {
                    resolve();
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    reject(error);
                });
        });
    }

    return authPreflightPromise.then(() => {
        return request(postsRequestData);
    });
}
```

Now I want to unit test the same without making the actual network calls. I learnt that popsicle is using fetch api, so I thought of using [fetch-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-mock) library and wrote the tests as shown in their examples but it is not capturing the network calls and my unit tests are still failing due to failed network calls.

Not sure where I'm going wrong.

```js
import fetchPosts from '../../src/fetchPosts.js';
const fetchMock = require('fetch-mock');

describe('tests for fetch posts ', () => {

    it('should return the posts returned by the api for valid requests', () => {

        // Mock the fetch() global to always return the same value for GET
        fetchMock.get('*', {foo: 'bar'});

        var fetchPostsPromise = fetchPosts(createValidRequest(username));

        return fetchPostsPromise.then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            expect(fetchMock.called()).equal(true);
            fetchMock.restore();
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            fetchMock.restore();
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

first, in your `fetchPosts`, I didn't see the defination of `authPreflightPromise`

then if you want to test asynchronous function, you should use `done callback`, or you will get a `timeout error`;

```
it('should return the posts returned by the api for valid requests', (done) => {

    fetchMock.get('*', {foo: 'bar'});

    var fetchPostsPromise = fetchPosts(createValidRequest(username));

    return fetchPostsPromise.then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        expect(myMock.called()).equal(true);
        fetchMock.restore();
        // tell mocha this test has finished
        done();
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        fetchMock.restore();
        done();
    });
// don't forget to set timeout, or you may get a timeout error
}).timeout(10000)
```